# Gap in the block chain synchronization when interrupted

Tags: synchronization

I was synchronizing the block chain with `geth --fast --cache=1024`. Then I got the message `synchronization failed` and I pressed `CTRL+C` because I had for some reasons to shutdown the VM [I am running several VMs on XenServer 6.5].

I noticed the last number: 558'400.

Then, after the same VM restarted I ran the synchronization command again and expected it will continue from the last number: ~558'400.
Surprisingly the first number which appeared was ~1'800'500.

**My question:**

Why this gap and am I wrong when I expected the starting number ~558'400?

Here a screenshot from the displayed information:

```
INFO .. Imported new state entries               count=500  elapsed=1ms        processed=7689495 pending=13579 retry=61  duplicate=284 unexpected=589
INFO .. Imported new block headers               count=2048 elapsed=6.299s     number=4891636 hash=23772e.3c586a ignored=0
INFO .. Imported new block receipts              count=26   elapsed=253ms      number=4854528 hash=0e47c8.c9be5a size=3.81mB   ignored=0
INFO .. Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=164 percentage=36 elapsed=6.418s
INFO .. Imported new block receipts              count=29   elapsed=234ms      number=4854557 hash=fe2e2a.fd00be size=3.86mB   ignored=0
INFO .. Imported new state entries               count=1195 elapsed=5ms        processed=7690690 pending=13169 retry=52  duplicate=284 unexpected=589
INFO .. Imported new block receipts              count=28   elapsed=292ms      number=4854585 hash=c50bbc.644e26 size=3.91mB   ignored=0
INFO .. Imported new block receipts              count=27   elapsed=186ms      number=4854612 hash=865a2f.e51e61 size=3.86mB   ignored=0
INFO .. Imported new state entries               count=1050 elapsed=5ms        processed=7691740 pending=12696 retry=0   duplicate=284 unexpected=589
INFO .. Imported new block receipts              count=26   elapsed=379ms      number=4854638 hash=65f38b.f2ae16 size=3.80mB   ignored=0
INFO .. Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=164 percentage=89 elapsed=9.463s
INFO .. Generated ethash verification cache      epoch=164 elapsed=10.146s
INFO .. Imported new block receipts              count=98   elapsed=869ms      number=4854736 hash=90e80c.2647ba size=13.99mB  ignored=0
INFO .. Imported new state entries               count=1041 elapsed=5ms        processed=7692781 pending=12391 retry=0   duplicate=284 unexpected=589
```

Comment: From where did you get those numbers? ie did you run `eth.syncing` or something else. Are those numbers blocks? Even in fast mode geth should download all blocks and verify they are correct, it also have to sync the Ethereum World state but it only sync to a recent state.

Comment: This are geth logs, so some of the information may appear mixed with other data. In fast mode some times it will download several blocks at once, but certainly a jumpt from 500k to 1.8M is quite large. But ethereum clients are quite resilent agains syncing problems, I'd not worry about it.

Comment: @Ismael Convert your comment into an answer and I'll accept it!